# Paralleling Multibit current DAC: Improving Accuracy by Averaging

Tags: parallel, current-source, dac, precision, linearity

No doubt that if I put in parallel n DACs, multibit (i.e. 16 bit) current output R2R ladder chips, I get n-times higher current at the summing node and the output impedance is also reduced by "n".

But what about linearity and precision at low signal levels? Can we apply the general law for "uncorrelated events", for which in summing configuration noise and tolerance (and, hence, DAC linearity and LSB -least significant bit- precision) may improve by SQRT(n) times?

Comment: If you turn off all but one DAC, there is no averaging-benefit.

Comment: digital inputs are in parallel too, so all n-DAC are always ON

Comment: It works for paralleled op-amps so why not.

Comment: that is  true for noise, but nothing is said about precision and linearity

Comment: If you have N k% current sources summed together, the equivalent current source will have k% error too. That's your circumstance. You can read more [here](http://lectureonline.cl.msu.edu/~mmp/labs/error/e2.htm).

Comment: Are R2R temperature coefficients uncorrelated? Likely not. Is tempco the most significant error source? Do you feed the same Vref to all R2R? Some intimate knowledge of error sources is required.

Answer (score 1):

This approach would work, barring any eccentricities in the particular DAC you're using.  Another approach is to run a single DAC faster than needed and low-pass it, which will potentially reduce noise but won't improve offsets or other errors inherent to the part.

Comment: Don't understand "barring eccentricity". Does linearity improve ( by SQRT ( n) )  if I get n miscellaneus parts in parallel coming from different lots?